# Display GMT time zone in php

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, gmt

How can I display like this `CountryName GMT +5.30 timezone` in php? .

The country names are fetching from the database and GMT calculations must be displayed based on the country name. I tried different functions like `get_defaulttimezone`,

But they are  not meeting my requirement. Ready to provide further details if required..

To get time zone Iam using this method :

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date_default_timezone_get() . ' => ' . date('e') . ' => ' . date('T');
```

But I think this is not the proper way

Comment: Can you please show your code what you tried so far ?

Comment: You can not determine the timezone to use based on the country name alone – there’s a lot of countries that are geographically so wide, that _several_ timezones are in use there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
// This will get an array of the timezones for Australia
$timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, "AU");
// Using the last element, which is 'Australia/Sydney'.
$timezone = new DateTimeZone(end($timezones));
$datetime = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
echo end($timezones). ' GMT ' . $datetime->format('P'); // +11:00
?>
```

This will output: Australia/Sydney GMT +11:00

The following will iterate every timezone for the countries within the array.

```
<?php

$countries = array( 'AF' => 'AFGHANISTAN', 'AL'=>'ALBANIA', 'DZ'=>'ALGERIA', 'AS'=>'AMERICAN SAMOA', 'AD'=>'ANDORRA', 'AO'=>'ANGOLA', 'AI'=>'ANGUILLA', 'AQ'=>'ANTARCTICA', 'AG'=>'ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA', 'AR'=>'ARGENTINA', 'AM'=>'ARMENIA', 'AW'=>'ARUBA', 'AU'=>'AUSTRALIA', 'AT'=>'AUSTRIA', 'AZ'=>'AZERBAIJAN', 'BS'=>'BAHAMAS', 'BH'=>'BAHRAIN', 'BD'=>'BANGLADESH', 'BB'=>'BARBADOS', 'BY'=>'BELARUS', 'BE'=>'BELGIUM', 'BZ'=>'BELIZE', 'BJ'=>'BENIN', 'BM'=>'BERMUDA', 'BT'=>'BHUTAN', 'BO'=>'BOLIVIA', 'BA'=>'BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA', 'BW'=>'BOTSWANA', 'BV'=>'BOUVET ISLAND', 'BR'=>'BRAZIL', 'IO'=>'BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN TERRITORY', 'BN'=>'BRUNEI DARUSSALAM', 'BG'=>'BULGARIA', 'BF'=>'BURKINA FASO', 'BI'=>'BURUNDI', 'KH'=>'CAMBODIA', 'CM'=>'CAMEROON', 'CA'=>'CANADA', 'CV'=>'CAPE VERDE', 'KY'=>'CAYMAN ISLANDS', 'CF'=>'CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC', 'TD'=>'CHAD', 'CL'=>'CHILE', 'CN'=>'CHINA', 'CX'=>'CHRISTMAS ISLAND', 'CC'=>'COCOS (KEELING) ISLANDS', 'CO'=>'COLOMBIA', 'KM'=>'COMOROS', 'CG'=>'CONGO', 'CD'=>'CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE', 'CK'=>'COOK ISLANDS', 'CR'=>'COSTA RICA', 'CI'=>'COTE D IVOIRE', 'HR'=>'CROATIA', 'CU'=>'CUBA', 'CY'=>'CYPRUS', 'CZ'=>'CZECH REPUBLIC', 'DK'=>'DENMARK', 'DJ'=>'DJIBOUTI', 'DM'=>'DOMINICA', 'DO'=>'DOMINICAN REPUBLIC', 'TP'=>'EAST TIMOR', 'EC'=>'ECUADOR', 'EG'=>'EGYPT', 'SV'=>'EL SALVADOR', 'GQ'=>'EQUATORIAL GUINEA', 'ER'=>'ERITREA', 'EE'=>'ESTONIA', 'ET'=>'ETHIOPIA', 'FK'=>'FALKLAND ISLANDS (MALVINAS)', 'FO'=>'FAROE ISLANDS', 'FJ'=>'FIJI', 'FI'=>'FINLAND', 'FR'=>'FRANCE', 'GF'=>'FRENCH GUIANA', 'PF'=>'FRENCH POLYNESIA', 'TF'=>'FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES', 'GA'=>'GABON', 'GM'=>'GAMBIA', 'GE'=>'GEORGIA', 'DE'=>'GERMANY', 'GH'=>'GHANA', 'GI'=>'GIBRALTAR', 'GR'=>'GREECE', 'GL'=>'GREENLAND', 'GD'=>'GRENADA', 'GP'=>'GUADELOUPE', 'GU'=>'GUAM', 'GT'=>'GUATEMALA', 'GN'=>'GUINEA', 'GW'=>'GUINEA-BISSAU', 'GY'=>'GUYANA', 'HT'=>'HAITI', 'HM'=>'HEARD ISLAND AND MCDONALD ISLANDS', 'VA'=>'HOLY SEE (VATICAN CITY STATE)', 'HN'=>'HONDURAS', 'HK'=>'HONG KONG', 'HU'=>'HUNGARY', 'IS'=>'ICELAND', 'IN'=>'INDIA', 'ID'=>'INDONESIA', 'IR'=>'IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF', 'IQ'=>'IRAQ', 'IE'=>'IRELAND', 'IL'=>'ISRAEL', 'IT'=>'ITALY', 'JM'=>'JAMAICA', 'JP'=>'JAPAN', 'JO'=>'JORDAN', 'KZ'=>'KAZAKSTAN', 'KE'=>'KENYA', 'KI'=>'KIRIBATI', 'KP'=>'KOREA DEMOCRATIC PEOPLES REPUBLIC OF', 'KR'=>'KOREA REPUBLIC OF', 'KW'=>'KUWAIT', 'KG'=>'KYRGYZSTAN', 'LA'=>'LAO PEOPLES DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC', 'LV'=>'LATVIA', 'LB'=>'LEBANON', 'LS'=>'LESOTHO', 'LR'=>'LIBERIA', 'LY'=>'LIBYAN ARAB JAMAHIRIYA', 'LI'=>'LIECHTENSTEIN', 'LT'=>'LITHUANIA', 'LU'=>'LUXEMBOURG', 'MO'=>'MACAU', 'MK'=>'MACEDONIA, THE FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF', 'MG'=>'MADAGASCAR', 'MW'=>'MALAWI', 'MY'=>'MALAYSIA', 'MV'=>'MALDIVES', 'ML'=>'MALI', 'MT'=>'MALTA', 'MH'=>'MARSHALL ISLANDS', 'MQ'=>'MARTINIQUE', 'MR'=>'MAURITANIA', 'MU'=>'MAURITIUS', 'YT'=>'MAYOTTE', 'MX'=>'MEXICO', 'FM'=>'MICRONESIA, FEDERATED STATES OF', 'MD'=>'MOLDOVA, REPUBLIC OF', 'MC'=>'MONACO', 'MN'=>'MONGOLIA', 'MS'=>'MONTSERRAT', 'MA'=>'MOROCCO', 'MZ'=>'MOZAMBIQUE', 'MM'=>'MYANMAR', 'NA'=>'NAMIBIA', 'NR'=>'NAURU', 'NP'=>'NEPAL', 'NL'=>'NETHERLANDS', 'AN'=>'NETHERLANDS ANTILLES', 'NC'=>'NEW CALEDONIA', 'NZ'=>'NEW ZEALAND', 'NI'=>'NICARAGUA', 'NE'=>'NIGER', 'NG'=>'NIGERIA', 'NU'=>'NIUE', 'NF'=>'NORFOLK ISLAND', 'MP'=>'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS', 'NO'=>'NORWAY', 'OM'=>'OMAN', 'PK'=>'PAKISTAN', 'PW'=>'PALAU', 'PS'=>'PALESTINIAN TERRITORY, OCCUPIED', 'PA'=>'PANAMA', 'PG'=>'PAPUA NEW GUINEA', 'PY'=>'PARAGUAY', 'PE'=>'PERU', 'PH'=>'PHILIPPINES', 'PN'=>'PITCAIRN', 'PL'=>'POLAND', 'PT'=>'PORTUGAL', 'PR'=>'PUERTO RICO', 'QA'=>'QATAR', 'RE'=>'REUNION', 'RO'=>'ROMANIA', 'RU'=>'RUSSIAN FEDERATION', 'RW'=>'RWANDA', 'SH'=>'SAINT HELENA', 'KN'=>'SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS', 'LC'=>'SAINT LUCIA', 'PM'=>'SAINT PIERRE AND MIQUELON', 'VC'=>'SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES', 'WS'=>'SAMOA', 'SM'=>'SAN MARINO', 'ST'=>'SAO TOME AND PRINCIPE', 'SA'=>'SAUDI ARABIA', 'SN'=>'SENEGAL', 'SC'=>'SEYCHELLES', 'SL'=>'SIERRA LEONE', 'SG'=>'SINGAPORE', 'SK'=>'SLOVAKIA', 'SI'=>'SLOVENIA', 'SB'=>'SOLOMON ISLANDS', 'SO'=>'SOMALIA', 'ZA'=>'SOUTH AFRICA', 'GS'=>'SOUTH GEORGIA AND THE SOUTH SANDWICH ISLANDS', 'ES'=>'SPAIN', 'LK'=>'SRI LANKA', 'SD'=>'SUDAN', 'SR'=>'SURINAME', 'SJ'=>'SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN', 'SZ'=>'SWAZILAND', 'SE'=>'SWEDEN', 'CH'=>'SWITZERLAND', 'SY'=>'SYRIAN ARAB REPUBLIC', 'TW'=>'TAIWAN, PROVINCE OF CHINA', 'TJ'=>'TAJIKISTAN', 'TZ'=>'TANZANIA, UNITED REPUBLIC OF', 'TH'=>'THAILAND', 'TG'=>'TOGO', 'TK'=>'TOKELAU', 'TO'=>'TONGA', 'TT'=>'TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO', 'TN'=>'TUNISIA', 'TR'=>'TURKEY', 'TM'=>'TURKMENISTAN', 'TC'=>'TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS', 'TV'=>'TUVALU', 'UG'=>'UGANDA', 'UA'=>'UKRAINE', 'AE'=>'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES', 'GB'=>'UNITED KINGDOM', 'US'=>'UNITED STATES', 'UM'=>'UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS', 'UY'=>'URUGUAY', 'UZ'=>'UZBEKISTAN', 'VU'=>'VANUATU', 'VE'=>'VENEZUELA', 'VN'=>'VIET NAM', 'VG'=>'VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH', 'VI'=>'VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.', 'WF'=>'WALLIS AND FUTUNA', 'EH'=>'WESTERN SAHARA', 'YE'=>'YEMEN', 'YU'=>'YUGOSLAVIA', 'ZM'=>'ZAMBIA', 'ZW'=>'ZIMBABWE', ); 

foreach ($countries as $code => $country) {
    $timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, $code);

    foreach ($timezones as $timezone_name) {
        $timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone_name);
        $datetime = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
        echo $country. ' GMT ' . $datetime->format('P') . ' ' . $timezone_name . '<br />';
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this Code,

You asked to display like this Country Name `GMT +5.30` timezone in `php`,

Here is my code,I hope it will help for You,.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");     //Country which we are selecting.

echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get();   //getting the Country name

echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s");       //year-Month-Day

$datetime = new DateTime('now', $timezone);     //Time

echo end($timezones). ' GMT ' , $datetime->format('P');     //GMT +5.30

?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
 date_default_timezone_set: Asia/Calcutta

    2014/02/20 

    16:16:42 

    GMT +05:30
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can use the **`list of supported timezones on PHP`**

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

```
 Protected/Config/Main

'timeZone'=>'America/Bogota',
```